# Register Car in Illinois and Get Plates

Tags: registration

I have a car which it's title and plates are registered in Wisconsin.  The title is in the name of name of Family member but is signed over to me.  I would like to register the car[ in my name] in Illinois.

I have found the [Illinois Cyber Drive Vehicle Services](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/vehicles/title_and_registration/home.html) page, and would normally think I'd need to go through the [Apply for Registration and Title](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/vehicles/title_and_registration/apply.html) content, but the plates and title are from out of state and I am unsure of how to proceed.

The [Title and Registration](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/vehicles/title_and_registration/pert.html) page briefly mentions "out-of-state" but none of the mentions seem to pertain to acquiring a car from out of state through a *private* transaction.

Could someone point me to information on how to transfer an out of state title to Illinois, registering the car, and acquiring Illinois Plates (all of which I would think should be able to be accomplished in a single step) for a vehicle?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare all of the paperwork listed on this page http://www.dmv.org/il-illinois/car-registration.php and travel to an SOS office where they'll issue you your plates.